# Python how to change "existing" variable

Tags: python

I have a little python application, and declared at the top of the application a string called lastMsg, in a function, this string should be changed, but instead of changing the existing string, it creates a new string, how can I change the old string?

Comment: How about sharing your code?

Comment: Can you not just assign the return value of the function to the variable? using globals is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

If I guessed correctly what you are trying to do (do share some code to further explain your answer):

You need to use the `global` keyword to specify you want to change the global variable.

```
myVar = "1"

def myFun():
    global myVar
    myVar = "2"

print(myVar)
myFun()
print(myVar)
```

Should print:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're asking.

I *think* you mean this:

```
lastMsg = "some string"

def a_function():
    lastMsg = "new value"
```

If so, you can change it using the `global` keyword:

```
lastMsg = "some string"

def a_function():
    global lastMsg

    lastMsg = "new value"
```